# Build a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ so that $T$ has no real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Build a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ so that $T$ has no real eigenvalues.

For this exercise it is sufficient to find a $4\times 4$ matrix $A$ so that $A$ has no real eigenvalues and define $Tx=Ax$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^4$.

I found one matrix $A$ in a book and this way is my solution.

Could you help me build this matrix by instead using the theory (some theorems) of linear algebra?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to do the problem for $T:{\bf R}^2\to{\bf R}^2$? Then think about a block diagonal matrix.

Comment: "Jack...which matrix of $2\times 2$ no have reals eigenvalues?

Comment: I tried making some grammatical corrections, can you make sure I didn't change the meaning of your question?

Comment: @LuisPrado: Think about the rotation matrices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Properties_of_a_rotation_matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
In fact, you can take any skew-symmetric real matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The companion matrix of $x^2+1$ has eigenvalues $i$ and $-i$ and hence no real eigenvalues.

This matrix is $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus taking the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & A \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

solves the problem.

This approach works for any field that is not algebraically closed. Just take a polynomial with no roots with a degree that divides the desired size of the matrix.